# Generating images: Alternate font by User Agent (OS)

Tags: asp.net, image, text, generator, fonts

I need to generate small images for certain parts of text. Those will have to fit into the text seamlessly. I know I can not make up for every browser font settings available, but how do I have to check for Linux, Mac and Windows users depending on the user agent? I want to use the right font (of the three "Verdana, Arial, Helvetiva") for the right user agent OS.

So:

1. How do I check for the OS? What do I have to compare to in the user agent?
2. Where can I get the other two fonts. Does the Windows-included Verdana look the same as the one used on Linux (or, is it free anyway? I don't know much about fonts)? Where do I get Helvetica? Is it Mac OS licensed?

Any code examples can be in either c# or VB.NET. I can read both.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For client side, have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

For server side, look at `Request.Browser.Platform`.

As for the fonts, I can't tell you much, except to make sure that you have a (virtual) machine that matches each platform you want to target. In my opinion, it's the only way to be really sure that whatever you end up doing actually works.

Comment: Request.Browser.Platform looks great. Now I just need to know what where I can get Helvetica...

Comment: Well I read up on the font thing and saw that Arial is in fact something modeled after Helvetica... 
http://www.ms-studio.com/articles.html
... So I would have to pay to get Helvetica without an Apple OS.
Alright, I'll just differentiate between Verdana and Arial then--

Answer (score 0):

If you use `@font-face` in your css and specify the font-size in pixels, you will get the same font on all platforms at a predictable size. Then you can create one set of images for all platforms.

Comment: I think they're trying to make images of email addresses to make it harder for spam bots to get them or something. If so, CSS `@font-face` wouldn't work.

Comment: Something like that. I want to generate images which fit into the text flow perfectly. And this for every of the 3 font familys.